# PHP insert query not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

```
<html>
   <body>
   <?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'users';
    $pw = '';
    $db = '#######';
    $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
               or die ("Could not connect.");

    mysql_select_db($db);

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','l','l','l','l','l','l')");
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
       print "Item added successfully.<br/>";
    }
    else{
       print "Item addition failed.<br/>";
    }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to insert these values into my database into the table `users` but when I run the code it keeps on saying "item addition failed" but I am not sure why, there is no problem with the database connection as I have already tested that, and I am not sure what's wrong with my insert query?

Comment: 7, ive checked all those technicalities, i hope.

Comment: You're runing your query twice you're aware of that right

Comment: You calling `mysql_query` two times. Also add `or die(mysql_error());` after mysql_query.

Comment: still giving me the failed message

Comment: Do not use the mysql API anymore! It's deprecated and insecure. Use PDO instead!

Comment: whats is the error message ?

Comment: AH, i added mysql_error and it says no database selected

Comment: so add USE name_of_your_db; before mysql_query("USE name_ofdb;"); or use mysql_select_db() function. However you should notice that mysql_* function are depracated.

Comment: Still says "no database selected"?

Comment: Try & check error using `mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Change `$db='########'` to proper DB name then after check. Also give proper connection parameter. Because you gave `$user = 'users';` and generally it should `$user='root'`. So also confirm you should have provided proper credentials to your MySql Connection and DB Name.

Comment: @NullVoid I've already pointed that in my post and comment.

Comment: @RobertPodwika: See at Rajiv Ranjan's last comment given by `faraday` that he/she is not sure about Username and Password.

Comment: But he doesn't get error "Could not connect" but "no database selected" so connection must be good.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems in your code. Firstly you do query twice. Secondly are you sure your db name is  $db = '#######'; change it to proper name.

To check if query was ok and if rows were added use **mysql_affected_rows()** to check errors use **mysql_error()**

Also change your sql engine to **PDO** or **mysqli** which are better.

**Please mind that Mysql_* functions are depracated.** That is why I've given you example how to use db connection in PDO.

```
<?php
   $host = 'localhost';
   $user = 'users';
   $pw = '';
   $db = '#######'; //CHANGE IT TO PROPER NAME WHERE TABLE users IS!
   $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
       or die ("Could not connect.");

   mysql_select_db($db);

  $sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO users VALUES('' ,'l','l','l','l', 'l','l')") or die(mysql_error());

  if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
     echo "Item added successfully.<br/>";
  else
     echo "Item addition failed.<br/>"; 
?>
```

I'll give you proper example how to do it with PDO cause if you still learn it'll help you :)

**PDO example**

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME;host=localhost';
$user = 'users';
$password = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO users VALUES('' ,'l','l','l','l', 'l','l');");
    echo $cout ? "Item added successfully" : "Item addition failed";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

The secure and good way to insert values is using prepared statements.
To create prepared statement you use

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES(?,?)");
$stmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com'));
```

[You can learn more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: +1 I appreciate that you came forward (I was thinking and found you gave just here) and provided a complete hint to @faraday. So that no more comments will be going for basic operations and he can get idea what he has to do with his question. And also give basic idea about mysql_* what you have already provided in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_query` twice. Change your code to:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('' ,'l','l','l','l', 'l','l')";
```

Comment: still giving the failed message

Comment: You have another problem in your code then. Check the database connection.

Answer (score 1):

try this.your called function mysql_query() twice.
on second time you passed it the result_set instead of query.

```
     <html>
     <body>
      <?php
       $host = 'localhost';
       $user = 'users';
       $pw = '';
       $db = '#######';
       $connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw)
           or die ("Could not connect.");


       mysql_select_db($db);

      $sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO users 
       VALUES('' ,'l','l','l','l', 'l','l')");

     if($sql){
        print "Item added successfully.<br/>";
      }
     else { print "Item addition failed.<br/>"; }
    ?>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: he should still use mysql_error to see if query failed. "Item addition failed.<br/>" is not good at development environment.

Comment: i added it and it says no database selected

Comment: match your database name properly as used here and phpmyadmin as well.

Comment: Check your database name then, the problem is with your connection.

Comment: ive checked that, is the connection part i did on top correct?

Comment: im not sure what to put for my password and user

Answer (score 1):

This should help you debug, you should look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead though... And of course remember to use the correct credentials, i presume you have removed them for safety :-)

```
mysql_select_db($db);

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','l','l','l','l','l','l')", $connect) OR die(mysql_error());
if($sql)
{
   print "Item added successfully.<br/>";
}
else{
   print "Item addition failed.<br/>";
}
?>
```